# Is it possible to have 2 podspecs within a single pod repo?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a private pod repo that contains unit tests.  I wanted the unit tests to run in the project that uses the pod rather than the pod project itself.

There might be a better way to do this entirely, but this was the setup I was thinking:

[image]

I am not sure if this is possible, if so, how do I specify which podspec each line in the podfile points to?

The [documentation](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod) says the podfile is assumed to be in the top level directory, but you can specify it to be another git location, however, I don't know if you can specify a location within the get repo?

```
pod 'JSONKit', :podspec => 'https://example.com/JSONKit.podspec'
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm guessing you can't have more than one spec per repo, but I'd be curious if you can somehow.

Comment: @JamieForrest - never figured this out, but it might be possible with subspecs

Comment: Good idea to use subspecs, although I don't think subspecs will work for me in my particular case. One of the frameworks I need a spec for is a set of test helpers. It seems like subspecs will automatically get installed when the parent pod is added to a Podfile. However, the test helper framework depends on `XCTest`, so installing into a non-test target will be problematic (unless I link the non-test target against `XCTest`, which would be weird too).